# I want to open multiple layouts using multiple button in android

Tags: android

i'm able to open 1 new activity(layout) with 1 button click but,
I want to open 4 different activities(layouts) with 4 different buttons clicks from main page.
I tried switch but failed.

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: post your code here please

Comment: not getting clearly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

In button declaration:

```
 btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
 btn1.setOnClickListener(click);

 btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
 btn2.setOnClickListener(click);

 btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
 btn3.setOnClickListener(click);

 btn4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
 btn4.setOnClickListener(click);
```

and the listener ...

```
 View.OnClickListener click= new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (v.getId()){

              case R.id.btn1:
                  activity1();
                  break;

              case R.id.btn2:
                  activity2();
                  break;

              case R.id.btn3:
                  activity3();
                  break;

              case R.id.btn4:
                  activity4();
                  break;

          }

      }
  };
```

Comment: View.OnClickListener click= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.bhindu:
                    (intent = new Intent(Hello.this,hindu.class);
                    break;

                case R.id.btoi:
                    (intent = new Intent(Hello.this,Toi.class);
                    break;
//continued

Comment: case R.id.bindian:
                    (intent = new Intent(Hello.this,Indian.class);
                    break;

                case R.id.bhindustan:
                    (intent = new Intent(Hello.this,Hindustan.class);
                    break;

            }

        }
    };
}

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhindu);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(click);

        btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btoi);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(click);

        btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bindian);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(click);

        btn4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhindustan);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(click);
    }

Comment: @NiksChandwani, if worked accept the answer as the correct answer clicking on the "V" icon, to make this question helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

you button click listener..

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        open(v);
    }
});
```

repeat this for all button

create method to open other activity

```
public void open(View v){
    Intent intent = null; 
      switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.but1:                 // your button id
           intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);         
          break;
       // -- so on
      }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

place all your activity intent in 2,3,4 case..

Comment: Thankyou for such a nice help

Comment: you have unaccepted the previous answer..what happen ...did it not worked...if worked appreciate the user...

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `View.OnClickListener` in your `MainActivity` and in `onClick` method do this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_1:
                 intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourClass1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.bt_2:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourClass2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.bt_3:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourClass3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.bt_4:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourClass4.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
```

and in you `onCreate()` method in `MainActivity` must set clickListener to evry `button` like this :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_1);
        btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_2);
        btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_3);
        btn4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_4);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
```

Comment: public class Hello extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button button;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhindu);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btoi);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bindian);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhindustan);

//continued in next comment

Comment: btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.bhindu:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this,hindu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.btoi:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this,Toi.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
break;

//continued in nxt

Comment: case R.id.bindian:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this,Indian.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.bhindustan:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this,Hindustan.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }


    }///end of Hello(main) class

Comment: what changes are needed please reply

Comment: I implemented your code by editing my variable name in your code

Comment: Actually I'm making a simple web view android project with 4 buttons on main screen,on every button click a newspaper site opens in a new layout activity

Comment: tell me what is the problem>? what happaned at all

Comment: sir,
as i told you I'm making  an android app to implement web view
I'm displaying 4 buttons on main screen, Out of 4 buttons only 1 button is working even after applying the switch code

Comment: can you edit your answer and post all code that you have because i cant understand where is the mistake that

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.niks.newstoday"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
            android:name=".Hello"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>

Comment: //manifest.xml continued

 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".hindu" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Toi" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Indian" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Hindustan" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: i must to go now i will write you after one hour ok?

Comment: total files =10
5 xml layout & 5 class files
Hello.java (Main class)
hindu.java (class for openeing newspaper webview)
Hindustan.java(class for openeing newspaper webview)
Indian.java(class for openeing newspaper webview)
Toi.java(class for openeing newspaper webview)

Same names goes for XML layout files(no problem with those files)

Comment: you can enter here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107051/31817 to talk about the problem

Comment: thanks for offering chat room,
I'm new to stack overflow so stack overflow doesn't allows me to chat

Comment: /*I'm using this code for sub classes for webview*/
public class hindu extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hindu);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://m.thehindu.com");

        //String customHtml = "<html><body><h2>Greetings from JavaCodeGeeks</h2></body></html>";
        //webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

}

Comment: /*posting again Hello.class (main class)*/

public class Hello extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhindu);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(click);

        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btoi);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(click);

Comment: btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bindian);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(click);

        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhindustan);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(click);
    }

Comment: View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch(v.getId())
            {

                case R.id.bhindu:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this, hindu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

Comment: case R.id.btoi:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this, Toi.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.bindian:
                    intent = new Intent(Hello.this, Indian.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.bhindustan:
                    intent  = new Intent(Hello.this, Hindustan.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }

        }
    };

}//end of (Hello) class main

Comment: if it works and im help you , u can accept my answer .